# Passing & storing multiple records into database at a time, in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, database, records

We have a data table in our ASP.NET application.  It is holding 800+ records.  Now we need to store all these records into database at a shot by using a SQL Server Stored Procedure.

Would you please let me know the best way to implement it and a reference code sample.

Thank you,
Regards.
Venkat.

Comment: Mind to be more specific about rows and a table (# of columns and types used), store method (insert/update), since many techniques are available to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkCopy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a(VS.80).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [SqlBullCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)?